# How do I emulate a USB stick with an external CDROM drive?

Tags: usb, iso, fat32, mkisofs

I am working with a Linux-based high-security network appliance (hereon: device) and do not have access to the user space so I can't log in. The only thing I can do is send it commands to upgrade through the USB port. It then reads the USB stick and starts the upgrade. I have been tasked to attempt to upgrade it without a USB stick but an external CDROM drive instead.
The USB stick must be less than 4GB and formatted with FAT32. Here is an example of a USB stick that the device recognizes:

```
[root@pitfall ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 15.6 GB, 15606349824 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14883 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x23ff8244

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               2         257      262144    b  W95 FAT32
```

I thought I could dd this USB partition and then manipulate the output in some way and burn it to a CD. Here is the file that resulted in that dd:

```
[root@pitfall ~]# file /tmp/dd_output
/tmp/dd_output: x86 boot sector, mkdosfs boot message display, code offset 0x3c, OEM-ID " mkdosfs", sectors/cluster 8, root entries 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 256, heads 64, sectors 524288 (volumes > 32 MB) , serial number 0xa740f5a9, label: "           ", FAT (16 bit)
```

I am not sure how to trick the device into thinking that the external CDROM drive is a USB stick. I imagine it will involve mkisofs in someway, but from what I can tell this command doesn't support vfat.
Here is the dmesg output for the external CDROM drive:

```
ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
ISOFS: changing to secondary root
usb 2-2: USB disconnect, address 5
usb 2-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7
usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=0c31
usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
usb 2-2: Product: USB to Serial-ATA bridge
usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Sunplus Innovation Technology.
usb 2-2: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFEDF102230086505
usb 2-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
scsi7 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
usb-storage: device found at 7
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
usb-storage: device scan complete
scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Slimtype DVD A  DS8A5S    WX13 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
```

Comment: cdroms show up as cdroms (srX) there's no way to make them hard drives (without rewriting parts of the kernel)

Comment: You could try to burn the USB stick contents on a DVD. I.e., do `dd if=/dev/usb of=/var/tmp/img bc=4096` and then burn `/var/tmp/img` as a raw image. That *might* work. In the worst case, you get a coaster, get a cold beer and relax.